# DDD: Referencing non aggregate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to improve my design using some DDD concepts. Currently I have 4 simple EF entites as shown in the following image:

[image]
There are multiple `TaskTemplates` each of them storing multiple `TasksItemTemplates`. The `TaskItemTemplates` contains various information (description, images, default processing times).

Users can create new concrete `Tasks` based on a `TaskTemplate`. In the current implementation, this will also create a `TaskItem` for every `TaskItemTemplate`, but in the future it might be possible to select one some relevant `TasksItemTemplates`.

I wonder how to model this requirement in DDD. The reference from `TaskItem` to `TaskTemplateItem` is not allowed, because `TaskTemplateItem` is not an aggregate root. But without this reference it is not possible to get the properties of the `TaskTemplateItem`.
Of course I could just drop the reference and copy all properties from `TaskTemplateItem` to `TaskItem`, but actually I like the possibility to update `TaskItems` by updating the `TaskTemplateItems`.

---

## Update: Expected behaviour on Task(Item)Template updates

It should be possible to edit `TaskTemplate` and `TaskItemTemplate` and e.g. fix Typos in Name or Description. I expect these changes to be reflected in the `Task/TaskItem`.
On the other hand, if the DefaultProcessingTime is modified, this should not change the persisted DueDate of a TaskItem.

In my current Implemenation it is not possible to add/remove `TaskItemTemplates` to a persisted `TaskTemplate`, but this would be a nice improvement. How would I implement something likes this? Add another entity `TaskTemplateVersion` between `TaskTemplate` and `TaskItemTemplate`?

## Update2: TaskItemTemplateId as ValueObject

After reading Vaughn's slides again, I think with a simple modification, my model is correct according to DDD:

[image]

Unfortunately I do not really understand, why this Design is better (is it better?). Okay, there won't be unnecessary db queries for TaskItemTemplates. But on the other side I almost ever need a TaskItemTemplate when working with a TaskItem and therefore everything gets more complicated. I cannot any longer do something like

```
public string Description
{
  get { return this.taskItemTemplate.Description; }
}
```

Comment: Btw, don't confuse DDD entities with EF entities.

Comment: I know in a perfect world there is a difference between DDD and EF. But there are also quite a lot of people trying to apply DDD concepts directly to EF.
I'm using DevExpress XAF with Views generated directly based on Entities.
Therefore it is not possible to develop a real DDD solution, but I think it is still possible to improve my design with it.

Comment: @krombi can you explain a bit more what you expect to happen to `TaskItems` when their `TaskItemTemplate` is modified ?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Based on the properties that you list beneath `TaskItem` and `TaskItemTemplate` I'd say that they should be *value objects* instead of *entities*. So if there isn't a reason (based on the information in your question there isn't) to make them entities, change them to immutable value objects.

With that solution, you just create a `TaskItem` from a `TaskItemTemplate` by copying its data.

Regarding the update scenario that you describe, it see the following solution:

- `TaskItem`s are created from a specific *version* of the `TaskItemTemplate`. Record that version with a `TaskItem`.
- The `TaskTemplate` is responsible for updating its items and keep track of their version.
- If a template changes, notify all `Task`s that are derived from the template if immediate action is required. If you just want to be able to "pull in" the template changes at a later time (instead of acting when the template changes), you just compare the versions.

To make informed decisions, it is very important that you fully understand the pros and cons of immutability. Only then you will see a benefit in modelling things as value objects. One source on the topic that I find very valuable is [Eric Lippert's series on immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx).

Also, the book *Implementing DDD* by Vaughn Vernon explains the concepts of value objects and entities very well.

Comment: First: Thank you! But I'm really confused about DDD. Although the concept of ValueObjects/Entities seems easy at first glance, you can find a lot of different opinion on SO.

TaskItem: It has a changeable TaskStatus. Therefore it is an entity, isn't it?

TaskItemTemplate: is it possible to have a collection of VOs? Some people say no.

Copy-On-Create approach: Yeah, this should work. The TaskItemTemplate also stores an Image property. Should I really copy this image multiple times?
I really like the DDD idea, but sometimes it is hard to leave the data-centric/DB/CRUD way.

Comment: Yes, if your TaskItem needs to be mutable, it cannot be a value object. But that makes your design A LOT more complex. You could try to manage the TaskStatus in the Task instead of in the item. I don't know if that makes sense in your application, though.
Why shouldn't lists of VOs be possible? That's ridiculous. You can create lists of numbers after all :-) .
The good thing about VOs (or rather immutable objects) is that they can be shared (because they are guaranteed no not change), so you don't need to copy the image.

Comment: I do not understand why design gets more complex if TaskItem is mutable. Can you elaborate more on this?
One problem I see: It is not possible to share TaskItem Entities, e.g. a Manager cannot watch a specific set of TaskItems, because they belong to a different AR. Watching a ValueObject would be possible. Confusing...

Argument against list of VOs: http://mhinze.com/2009/01/10/there-is-never-a-collection-of-value-objects/

If I would model TaskItemTemplate as a VO and use your Version concept, how would I search for TaskItems to update? I have to search by equality if there is no identity?!

Comment: Sorry to say, but the article you linked is absolute rubbish. Not only shows the author **mutable** value objects in his example, he also did not understand the concept of value objects at all.

Comment: What about http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/261444/implementing-ddd-by-vernon-value-object-or-not
Vernon also uses a Collection of Entities instead of ValueObjects due to db constraints.
Don't get me wrong: I really appreciate your help, but I'm still confused. Everything makes sense when reading blogs/books/SO questsions, but if I try to adapt it to my problems, I'm a little bit lost.